# Singularities of $f(z)=\dfrac{z}{\sin\pi z^{2}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Consider the function $f(z) = \dfrac{z}{\sin\pi z^{2}}$.  It has a simple pole at $z=0$.  There are also 4 poles at $z=\pm\sqrt{n}$ and $z=\pm i\sqrt{n}$, where $n\in Z^{+}$.  What is the order of the pole?

Comment: It also belongs to Mathematical Physics(Complex Analysis).

Comment: Complex analysis without physics context?  Mathematicians not good enough for it?